# How to combine two observables together in Rxjs iif conditional operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

It excites me to see rxjs observables in action and it confuses every single time, but each time I fell more in love with them.

Well, I have three observables -

1. an observable that refreshed based on timer `this.autoRefreshView$`
2. a default observable that fetches based on today date `this.intraDayView`
3. an observable that fetches based on yesterday's date (let's say) `this.priorDayView$`

There is a `BehaviourSubject<>` that emits if default observable view is to be fetched (based on current date) or yesterday's view based on a view property - `today` or `yesterday`.

I want to execute `this.autoRefreshView$` only when emitted value is `today`. But, below it's executed if value is `yesterday` as well. Is my merge here incorrect? Following is what I tried -

```
this.dashboardViewService.dashboardView$
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((v) =>
          iif(
            () => v === 'today',
            merge(this.intraDayView$, this.autoRefreshView$),
            this.priorDayView$
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe((response) => {
        if (response.date) {
          this.dateService.setDate(response.date);
          this.date= response.date;
        }
      });
```

This seems to work for me but the problem is when the view is not `today`, it still gets into `merge(this.intraDayView$, this.autoRefreshView$)` and executes `this.autoRefreshView$` and updates the view, which I need to update only when event is `today` and not `yesterday`.

Any suggestion as what is missing? Please let me know if any other details are required.

I think it's because `autoRefreshView` is emitted based on timer, so may be when it's called for first time, timer is set? Is there a way to handle that elegantly ?

```
this.autoRefreshView$ = timer(0, 25000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
 
          );
      ....
      ....
```

UPDATE - Updating the question with complete code snippet -

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.intraDayView$ = this.api.getLatestData();
    this.priorDayView$ = this.api.getPastData();

    
    this.autoRefreshView$ = timer(0, 500000)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
                // new data should be available, call the api
                return this.api.getLatestData();
             });

    this.getDashboardView();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dashboardViewSusbscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  getDashboardView() {
    this.dashboardViewService.dashboardView$
      .pipe(
        switchMap((v) =>
          iif(
            () => v === 'today',
            merge(this.intraDayView$, this.autoRefreshView$),
            this.priorDayView$
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe((response) => {
        if (response.date) {
          this.dateService.setDate(response.date);
          this.date= response.date;
        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `autoRefresh$` continues to be executed, is because you are using [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap), which will create an additional "inner observable" every time it receives an emission. It does not stop listening to the previous source, which continues to propagate emissions from `autoRefresh$`.

You can instead use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) which maintains only a single inner source; so it stops listening to old sources when it receives a new emission:

```js
this.dashboardViewService.dashboardView$.pipe(
    switchMap(v => iif(
        () => v === 'today',
        merge(this.intraDayView$, this.autoRefreshView$),
        this.priorDayView$
    ))
)
```

Comment: I am gonna try it mate and update you here. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

[I've put together a StackBlitz here based on what I think you are asking.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sznpcp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.component.ts)

I have made a few assumptions. I have made a fake API call to show that something is returned on every emission of the timer if you want today's data and that only one request is made if you request a previous day's data. You'll see the view update accordingly.

Instead of the `intraDayView$`, why not do something like this:

```
  autoRefreshView$: Observable<{ data: string, requestedAt: string }> = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      this.dashboardService.getDataForDay(new Date().toISOString())
    )
  );
```

We can then use `autoRefreshView$` in a similar way you had, using `iif`.

```
finalView$: Observable<{ data: string, requestedAt: string }> = this.dashboardView$.pipe(
    switchMap((dashboardView: string) =>
      iif(
        () => dashboardView === 'today',
        this.autoRefreshView$,
        this.dashboardService.getDataForDay(dashboardView).pipe(take(1))
      )
    )
  );
```

Part of your issue was that you needed to use a `switchMap`, not `mergeMap`. `switchMap` will only maintain one inner source observable, so will cancel an in-flight observable should a new emission from your `BehaviorSubject` happen.
So, in this case, what happens is:

1. Subscribe to whatever the dashboard view is set to
2. If it is 'today', then subscribe to a timer, where on every emission, you call your service to fetch your dashboard data.
3. If it changes to a given date that isn't today, fetch the data for that day, making only one API call with `take(1)` (I am assuming that if it's not `today`, you will just want one API call for all the data for that day).

Also, some advice I would give is to make use of Angular templates like so:

```
<p *ngIf="finalView$ | async; let finalView">
  {{ finalView | json }}
</p>
```

Angular will manage the subscription and unsubscription for you here, so you won't have any trailing subscriptions left lying around.

Comment: thank you for all the efforts. I will share my findings with you.

Comment: Please remember to mark an answer as accepted if you have found one that helped you!

Comment: surely, but it doesn't work for me. I am gonna update my question with complete code snippet. Sorry, got a bit delayed in trying it out.

Comment: I update the question at the end with the actual code snippet. Now no api calls are being made at all, where am I missing, could you please take a look?

Comment: thanks deaks, your suggestion of using `switchMap` and not `mergeMap` definitely helped. why I can't get rid of `intraday$` is because that timer has inner logic of executing the code between some time points based on a time zone. So I had to call a default intraday view when it doesn't fall in the timezone. Not sure I am able to communicate the requirement, it's a bit weird. But Your suggestion helped and I am upvoting your answer mate. Thanks for all the help !!